# Extract common element from 2 tuples python

Tags: python, tuples

I have 2 tuples A & B. How can I extract the common elements of A & B to form a new tuple?
For example:

```
    A -> (1,'a',(2,'b'),3,'c',4)
    B -> (1,(2,'b'),4,8)
    new_tuple -> (1,(2,'b'),4)
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you perform some research before posting? like google? because that one is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

With `set` intersection (to return a new *set* with elements common to the set and all others):

```
A = (1,'a',(2,'b'),3,'c',4)
B = (1,(2,'b'),4,8)
result = tuple(set(A) & set(B))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
(1, 4, (2, 'b'))
```

---

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.intersection

Answer (score 0):

You could use set intersection. Note that this doesn't guarantee anything about the order of the elements.

```
>>> A = (1,'a',(2,'b'),3,'c',4)
>>> B = (1,(2,'b'),4,8)
>>> tuple(set(A).intersection(set(B)))
(1, (2, 'b'), 4)
```