# Remove tuple from list similar to tuple in another list

Tags: python, list, tuples

i am new to python and to programming in general. I have a problem with removing tuples from a list that have similarity with tuples from another list.

```
List1=[(1,2,3,4,5),(1,3,6,7,8)]
```

`List2=[(1,2,3,7,9),(1,4,8,9,10),(1,3,8,9,10)]`

I want to remove tuples from List2 that have 3 similar elements in tuples of List1.

```
Outputlist=[(1,4,8,9,10)]
```

What is the most efficient way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may get more help if you attempt some code yourself and post it in your question. Something like the following may help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405959/extract-common-element-from-2-tuples-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a for loop, and each time your criteria is met, delete that element from `List2` and go to the next one:

```
List1=[(1,2,3,4,5),(1,3,6,7,8)]
List2=[(1,2,3,7,9),(1,4,8,9,10),(1,3,8,9,10)]

for index, elem2 in enumerate(List2):
    for elem1 in List1:
        # Find common items using set intersection.
        commonItems = len(set(elem2).intersection(set(elem1)))
        if commonItems == 3:
            del List2[index]
            break

print(List2)
```

This will return:

```
[(1, 4, 8, 9, 10)]
```